How to get the first element of a groupedby array by the ip?
I'm trying to get the first element of each object ip and then concat them and push them in an array, then take the second element and so on..
here is the grouped by ip array
{
  "ip1.x.x.x": [
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin1"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin2"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin3"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin4"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin5"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin6"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin7"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin8"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin9"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "ip2.x.x.x": [
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin10"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin11"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin12"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin13"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin14"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin15"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin16"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "ip3.x.x.x": [
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin17"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin18"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin19"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin20"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin21"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "coin": "coin22"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin23"
      },
      {
        "coin": "coin24"
      }
    ]
  ],
  etc..
}

the expected result should be as follows
[
  [
    {
      "coin": "coin1"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin2"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin3"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin4"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin5"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin10"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin11"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin12"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin13"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin14"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin17"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin18"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin19"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin20"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin21"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "coin": "coin6"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin7"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin8"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin9"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin15"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin16"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin22"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin23"
    },
    {
      "coin": "coin24"
    }
  ]
]

as you can see I took the 1st element in the array of each ip and concat and pushed them to new array, then I took the 2nd element, and if there is 3rd element I'll keep doing so till the object keys are done.
Now what I've tried to do is the following


const chunkArray = (array, chunkSize) => {
  return Array.from({
      length: Math.ceil(array.length / chunkSize)
    }, (_, index) =>
    array.slice(index * chunkSize, (index + 1) * chunkSize)
  );
};

let data_in_chunks_array = [];
let data_obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(groupedByIp).length; i++) {
  const ip = Object.keys(groupedByIp)[i];

  let data_in_chunks_ip = chunkArray(groupedByIp[ip], 5);

  data_obj[ip] = data_in_chunks_ip;
}

console.log('data_obj', data_obj);
<script>
  let groupedByIp = {
    'ip1.x.x.x': [{
        coin: 'coin1',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin2',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin3',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin4',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin5',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin6',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin7',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin8',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin9',
      },
    ],
    'ip2.x.x.x': [{
        coin: 'coin10',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin11',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin12',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin13',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin14',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin15',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin16',
      },
    ],
    'ip3.x.x.x': [{
        coin: 'coin17',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin18',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin19',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin20',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin21',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin22',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin23',
      },
      {
        coin: 'coin24',
      },
    ],
  };
</script>



This will return the first example data. Now I can't figure out the second part where I take the 1st element of each ip array and concat them and keep doing so till they are all have been taken, like (remove at index) for example.

@cmgchess what inputs?!! (1st example output is the grouped by ip array) (2nd example output should be the output result) (3rd example code is the code you should try to get the 1st example output)

my bad got confused

something like this? https://codeshare.io/de6yRz

@cmgchess can you add your solution to answers pls

What is this in this.chunkArray()? The code isn't in a class method.

@Barmar it's a method in a class, you can create an arrow function instead

why my code has changed, I didn't add snippet or anything like that, the one who edited the code broke it

Why not just write chunkArray(...)? The class is irrelevant to the question.

How did I break it? All I did was wrap it in the snippet, and put the function definition before the use so it doesn't get an undefined runction error.

@Barmar why add the let groupedByIp = {} in a script, it should be at the top of my example code

This is a trick to make the code snippet easier to read. Put the data in the HTML box so you don't have to scroll past it to get to the functions that process it.

@Barmar ah ok thank you, I didn't know that

This conversion has the concept of [transposing a maxtrix), together with concatenating the inner arrays (for which flatMap can serve), and ignoring the keys of the original object (for which we can use Object.values).
So:


const transposeFlat = arr => arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.flatMap(row => row[i]));

// Your example data:
const data = {"ip1.x.x.x": [[{"coin": "coin1"},{"coin": "coin2"},{"coin": "coin3"},{"coin": "coin4"},{"coin": "coin5"}],[{"coin": "coin6"},{"coin": "coin7"},{"coin": "coin8"},{"coin": "coin9"}]],"ip2.x.x.x": [[{"coin": "coin10"},{"coin": "coin11"},{"coin": "coin12"},{"coin": "coin13"},{"coin": "coin14"}],[{"coin": "coin15"},{"coin": "coin16"}]],"ip3.x.x.x": [[{"coin": "coin17"},{"coin": "coin18"},{"coin": "coin19"},{"coin": "coin20"},{"coin": "coin21"}],[{"coin": "coin22"},{"coin": "coin23"},{"coin": "coin24"}]],}
const res = transposeFlat(Object.values(data));
console.log(res);




I com up with a solution as follows
const get_data_in_chunks_new = (dataGroupedByIp) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let data_obj = {};
    let data_obj_tmp = {};
    let data_in_chunks_new = [];

    const chunkArray = (array, chunkSize) => {
      return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(array.length / chunkSize) }, (_, index) =>
        array.slice(index * chunkSize, (index + 1) * chunkSize)
      );
    };

    const customizer = (objValue, srcValue) => {
      if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return objValue.concat(srcValue);
      }
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataGroupedByIp).length; i++) {
      const ip = Object.keys(dataGroupedByIp)[i];

      let data_in_chunks_ip = chunkArray(dataGroupedByIp[ip], 5);

      data_obj[ip] = {};

      for (let y = 0; y < data_in_chunks_ip.length; y++) {
        const chunk = data_in_chunks_ip[y];

        data_obj[ip][y] = chunk;
      }
    }

    let args = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data_obj).length; i++) {
      const ip = Object.keys(data_obj)[i];

      args.push(data_obj[ip]);
    }

    data_obj_tmp = _.mergeWith(...args, customizer);

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data_obj_tmp).length; i++) {
      const key = Object.keys(data_obj_tmp)[i];

      data_in_chunks_new.push(data_obj_tmp[key]);
    }

    return resolve(data_in_chunks_new);
  });
};

get_data_in_chunks_new({
  "ip1.x.x.x": [
    {
      coin: "coin1",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin2",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin3",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin4",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin5",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin6",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin7",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin8",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin9",
    },
  ],
  "ip2.x.x.x": [
    {
      coin: "coin10",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin11",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin12",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin13",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin14",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin15",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin16",
    },
  ],
  "ip3.x.x.x": [
    {
      coin: "coin17",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin18",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin19",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin20",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin21",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin22",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin23",
    },
    {
      coin: "coin24",
    },
  ],
}).then(result => console.log(result));

It seems to work for me, it's based on lodash lib
